# How can i open a new private window using safari extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, safari, safari-extension

I'm now converting my chrome extension to safari extension.

My chrome extension uses the API to open a new private window like this.

```
chrome.windows.create({"url": url, "incognito": true});
```

Does anyone know the way to implement this functionality in safari extension?

I tried looking it up, but I could only find the way to open a normal window as below.
`safari.application.openBrowserWindow();`

Comment: I have no experience with Safari but according to [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/safariextensions/safaribrowsertab) you can set tab's `private` flag to `true`, so I guess you'll need to either alter the active tab if it exists upon window creation or add a new tab with the flag set.

Comment: Thank you for giving advice, but the docs says tab's `private` is a read only attribute. So I can't change the value intensionally.

Answer (score 3):

As of Safari 10.0 and macOS 10.12, there is no public API to accomplish this.

For Safari Extensions written in Javascript, [the `private` attribute of `SafariBrowserTab` is read-only](https://developer.apple.com/reference/safariextensions/safaribrowsertab/1635351-private).

For Safari App Extensions (new in Safari 10), [the `usesPrivateBrowsing` property of `SFSafariPageProperties` is also read-only](https://developer.apple.com/reference/safariservices/sfsafaripageproperties/1638100-usesprivatebrowsing).

Either of the above can only be used to query the private browsing state of a tab.

And the respective open window and open tab methods (for Safari Extensions JS and Safari App Extensions) do not currently provide any ability to configure private browsing mode either.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I give up trying to open a private window in my safari extension.